# Shell how to assign a result of string test in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I ve a shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash
server=$1
modules=$2
is_selected= if [[ $modules== *"myModule"* ]]; then true else false fi
```

I want that if the condition `$modules== *"myModule"*` is verified ,

then the variable **is_selected** gets `true` , else `false`

**How may i adjust it in one line ?**

Comment: You can set a default value is_selected=false first before if condition then do a if test and if it is true then reset the is_selected=true;

Comment: [[ $2 == *"myModule"* ]] ;echo $?    
where "0" mean true

Comment: add a space between `$modules` and the `==` comparison, equality sign. Another `;` after the `true` since it represents a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need command substitution, and you command has to *output* the string `true` or `false`.

```
is_selected=$( if [[ $modules == *"myModule"*; then echo true; else echo false; fi)
```

Or put the assignment *in* the `if` statement:

```
if [[ $modules == *myModule* ]]; then is_selected=true; else is_selected=false; fi
```

which has the benefit of not requiring a subshell (and likely a new process) for the command substitution.

Or using a suggestion from the comments, initialize the variable to false,
then set it to true if the match succeeds.

```
is_selected=false; [[ $modules == *myModule* ]] && is_selected=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a command substitution and echo the desired result:

```
is_selected=$(if [[ "$modules" == *"myModule"* ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi)
```